# Spark SQL failed in Spark Streaming (KafkaStream)

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I use Spark SQL in a Spark Streaming Job to search in a Hive table.
Kafka streaming works fine without problems. If I run `hiveContext.runSqlHive(sqlQuery);` outside `directKafkaStream.foreachRDD` it works fine without problems. But I need the Hive-Table lookup inside the streaming job. The use of JDBC (`jdbc:hive2://`) would work, but I want to use the Spark SQL.

The significant places of my source code looks as follows:

```
// set context
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
SparkContext sparkSqlContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(batchDuration));
HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(sparkSqlContext);

// Initialize Direct Spark Kafka Stream. Starts from top
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream =
                KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(streamingContext,
                        String.class,
                        String.class,
                        StringDecoder.class,
                        StringDecoder.class,
                        kafkaParams,
                        topicsSet);

// work on stream                   
directKafkaStream.foreachRDD((Function<JavaPairRDD<String, String>, Void>) rdd -> {
    rdd.foreachPartition(tuple2Iterator -> {
        // get message
        Tuple2<String, String> item = tuple2Iterator.next();

        // lookup
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT something FROM somewhere";
        Seq<String> resultSequence = hiveContext.runSqlHive(sqlQuery);
        List<String> result = scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(resultSequence);

        });
    return null;
});

// Start the computation
streamingContext.start();
streamingContext.awaitTermination();
```

I get no meaningful error, even if I surround with try-catch.

I hope someone can help - Thanks.

//edit:
The solution looks like:

```
// work on stream                   
directKafkaStream.foreachRDD((Function<JavaPairRDD<String, String>, Void>) rdd -> {
    // driver
    Map<String, String> lookupMap = getResult(hiveContext); //something with hiveContext.runSqlHive(sqlQuery);
    rdd.foreachPartition(tuple2Iterator -> {
        // worker
        while (tuple2Iterator != null && tuple2Iterator.hasNext()) {
            // get message
            Tuple2<String, String> item = tuple2Iterator.next();
            // lookup
            String result = lookupMap.get(item._2());
        }
    });
    return null;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you want to use Spark SQL it won't make it possible. Spark's rule number one is no nested actions, transformations or distributed data structures.

If you can express your query for example as join you can use push it to one level higher to `foreachRDD` and this pretty much exhaust your options to use Spark SQL here:

```java
directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> 
   hiveContext.runSqlHive(sqlQuery)
   rdd.foreachPartition(...)
)
```

Otherwise direct JDBC connection can be a valid option.

Comment: Which way is better if you need a table lookup with a specific value from Kafka message to process the message?

Comment: Do you mean join vs query over jdbc?

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. I thought my plan is already a mistake. So that I spark misused.

Comment: Direct jdbc connection (without using SQLContext and Dataframes) inside an action is a valid approach. You simply cannot access SQLContext / SparkSession inside an action. Regarding jdbc vs Spark SQL operation for each rdd a lot depends on what exactly is `SELECT something FROM somewhere`. In practice I would benchmark both (considering broadcast joins as well) and simply check which one behaves better in particular scenario.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me. I get a lot's of errors it try to run sql query at this position. Some SparkException like `SerializableConfiguration cannot be cast to [B`.

Comment: If you have objects which are not serializable these have to be initialized per executor. This is not specific to this particular case.

Comment: To use the hiveContext at the driver-position is right. It is not possible to use dataframe at this position, because it failed to close. I'm not sure why.